# Select tag placeholder

Tags: html, angular

I have following select tag code in angular 7

```
<select class="form-control fixed-select" name="country" #country=ngModel
                  [(ngModel)]="employeeObject.address.country.id" (change)="onCountrySelect($event.target.value, false)"
                  required>
                  <option value="" selected disabled>Select country</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value={{country.id}}>{{country.countryCode}}</option>
                </select>
```

Default selection is not working even I used SELECTED attribute.
How to solve this?

Comment: Please explain what's going on with your error. 'selected' allows to display the item by default : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bafamb (working example)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't see any select option in the link provided by you

Comment: I fixed the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bafamb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: can u provide more information about the error By default selected option works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crqsky

Comment: When I copy paste above code in stackblitz it is working ... 
But y not it is working in my application?

Comment: Try to use property binding [selected]=true

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `country` must be have empty string as value to match with your option.

Comment: My countries variable is empty array which means country variable has "" value as default .